# CXF wsdl2java not reading schema properly

Tags: xsd, cxf, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

I am using below wsdl2java plugin configured to generate java classes using WSDL.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>src/main/resources/XXXXService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <validate>none</validate>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-server</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>http://XXX/YY=XXX</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>

                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now, I have below schema included in my WSDL.

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="myschema.xsd" xmlns="tns"></xsd:include>
```

When my element definition is within my WSDL like below, it generates a class for **myElement** , which is fine:

```
<xsd:element name="myElement">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="a" type="xsd:string"
                    minOccurs="1">
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:string"
                    minOccurs="1">
                </xsd:element>                  
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

But when my element definition in WSDL refers to a ComplexType definition in schema. Then the element class **aaa** doesn't get generated only **aaaType** class gets generated.

```
<xsd:element name="aaa"
        type="tns:aaaType">
</xsd:element>
```

Is there a way I can specify wsdl2java to generate both classes **aaa** and **aaaType** and reference **aaaType** inside **aaa** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `xmlns:tns` and `targetNamespace` on both WSDL and the schema.

`<xsd:element name="aaa"`... - it can be defined in schema itself.

You can try to browse the WSDL and check if it is proper, as issue seems to be related to schema include.